# Watch one property with several handlers

Tags: vue.js, watch

Is there a way to watch a single property with several handlers?

I need it because I need some instructions to be `immediate`, and some others not. I guess the only solution for this is to create 2 watchers for the same property, if it is possible.

Something like this would be great, but this doesn't work since the first watcher on `myProp` is overriden:

```
watch: {
    myProp: {
        immediate: true,
        handler () {
            // instructions
        }
    },
    myProp() {
        // instructions
    }
}
```

Live test [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/zw3y6rwn4l)

Comment: Maybe showing some code can make others do understand what you are asking. Even better you can create a codesanbox example

Comment: @roliroli  done.

Comment: Thanks but still I can't understand what you want to do. Can you show what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a watcher by calling [`vm.$watch`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch). You might do that for the `immediate` one, in the `created` section, to be explicit about when it first fires.